# List of top-bar buttons is going behind a div for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
/* Dropdown */
li.dropdown{position: relative;}
ul.dropdown-menu{
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 120px;
}
ul.dropdown-menu li{
  display: block !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Bahrain Bourse</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Fonts.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Site.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Slideshow.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif}
.mySlides {display: none}
</style>
<body>




<!-- Navbar -->
<div class="w3-container w3-black w3-top"> 
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a class="w3-button" style="font-size:24px" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li> 
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle w3-button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Corporate Profile</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle w3-button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Quotes & Markets</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle w3-button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Prodcuts & Services</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle w3-button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Investors</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle w3-button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Rules & Regulations</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle w3-button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Brokers</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle w3-button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Bahrain Clear</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle w3-button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Publications</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle w3-button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">News & Events</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am working on a page that has top-bar navigation, and below it a slideshow div with images.

Anyways, when I click on one of the options from top-bar, it somehow display the children options behind the slideshow. I don't what is the reason, so please help!

I attached 2 images to clarify the thing for you.

Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXgYX.png)

[image]

```html
<div class="w3-container w3-black w3-top">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>
      <a class="w3-button" style="font-size:24px" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle w3-button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Corporate Profile</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, just raise the z-index of your nav? Like `ul.nav{ z-index:2; }` ? Instead of the default 0

Comment: I tried, but nothing changed!

Answer (score 0):

you are missing end tag of parent list `</ul>` before end tag of `</div>`

change your code to this

```
<div class="w3-container w3-black w3-top"> 
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>
      <a class="w3-button" style="font-size:24px" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      </a>
    </li> 
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle w3-button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Corporate Profile</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    </ul> <!--this was missing-->
</div>
```

Comment: It's not missing in my code, it's just missing from here because I didn't include all the options (<li>'s) I got.

Comment: you need to show  all  HTML and css coded  in order to figure out your issue

Comment: I have added it.